# I'm trying to calculate the appetizers price from PreferenceData with the main meal but when I press add to cart only meal price calculate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

here is my code using context hook to add the meal to cart and calculate its price

```
const CartStateContext = createContext();
const CartDispatchContext = createContext();


const initialState = {
    products: restaurantMenu.flatMap(({ menu }) => menu),
    cart: [],
};
    
const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD':
            const item = state.products.find(
                (product) => product.id === action.payload.id
            );
            // Check if Item is in cart already
            const inCart = state.cart.find((item) =>
                item.id === action.payload.id ? true : false
            );
        
            return {
            ...state,
            cart: inCart
                ? state.cart.map((item) =>
                    item.id === action.payload.id
                    ? { ...item, qty: item.qty + 1 }
                    : item
                )
                : [...state.cart, { ...item, qty: 1 }],
            };
            
        case 'DELETE':
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: state.cart.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id),
            };
        
        case 'INCREASE':
            const tempCart = state.cart.map((cartItem) => {
                if (cartItem.id === action.payLoad.id) {
                    return { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty + 1 };
                }
                return cartItem;
            });
            return { ...state, cart: tempCart };
        
        case 'DECREASE':
            const temp = state.cart.map((cartItem) => {
                if (cartItem.id === action.payLoad.id) {
                    return { ...cartItem, qty: cartItem.qty - 1 };
                }
                return cartItem;
            })
            .filter((cartItem) => cartItem.qty !== 0);
            return { ...state, cart: temp };
                
        case 'CLEAR':
            return {cart :[]}
            
        default:
            throw new Error(`unknow action.${action.type}`)
    }

}

export const CartProvider =({children})=>{
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,initialState)
    return(
        <CartDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        <CartStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            {children}
        </CartStateContext.Provider>

        </CartDispatchContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useCart = ()=>useContext(CartStateContext);
export const useDispatch =()=> useContext(CartDispatchContext);
```

Here is the code where I display the meal details with appetizer from dummydata

```
const OrderScreen= ({navigation, route})=>{

const {index,item} = route.params;
const [state,setState] = React.useState([])

const opacity = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
const {dark} = useContext(ThemeContext)

{/*Change Basket Value*/}
const {cart} = useCart();
const [cartCount, setCartCount]=React.useState(0);
  
{/*Culcalate Total*/}
const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = React.useState(0);
const [totalItems, setTotalItems] = React.useState(0);
  
  
useEffect(() => {
    let items = 0;
    let price = 0;
    
    cart.forEach((item) => {
        items += item.qty;
        price += item.qty * item.price;
    });
    
    setTotalItems(items);
    setTotalPrice(price);
},);
  
  
useEffect(()=>{
    let count = 0;
    cart.forEach((item)=>{
        count +=item.qty;
    });
    setCartCount(count)
})
  
  
{/*Add Item to Cart*/}
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const addToCart = (item)=>{
    dispatch({type:'ADD', payload:item});
}
  

    
return(
    <Modal animationType='slide'>
        <View style={{flex:1,  backgroundColor: dark ? COLORS.darkColor : COLORS.gray3, }}>
    

        {/*Mini Meal Additional*/}
        {index.preferenceData.map(items=>(
            <View  style={{marginTop:SIZES.padding}}>
                <View style={styles.view7} key={items.id}>
                    <Text style={styles.text8}>{dummyData?.restaurantMenu[item].preferenceTitle[index.preferenceData.indexOf(items)]}</Text>
            
                    {
                        index.required[index.preferenceData.indexOf(items)] &&
                            <View style={styles.view9}>
                                <Text style={styles.text7}>{index.minimum[index.preferenceData.indexOf(items)]} REQUIRED</Text>
                            </View>
                    }
        
                </View>
    
                <View style={styles.view10}>
                    {items.map(item =>
                        <TouchableOpacity key={item.id}
                            onPress={()=>{
                                const id = index.preferenceData.indexOf(items)
                                if(index.minimum[id] !==null)
                                { 
                                    const check = items.filter(item =>item.checked?item:null)
                                    index.preferenceData[id].forEach(i=>{
                                    if(i.id === item.id){
                                        if(check.length < index.minimum[id])
                                        {
                                        i.checked = !i.checked
                                        }
                                        else{
                                        i.checked = false
                                        }
                                    }
                                    })
                                    index.counter[id] = index.counter[id]+1
                                    setState({
                                        prefernce:[...index.preferenceData],
                                        counter:[...index.counter]
                                    })
                                } else{
                                    index.preferenceData[id].forEach(i=>{
                                        if(i.id===item.id){
                                            i.checked = !i.checked
                                        }
                                    })
                                    setState({preferenceData:[...state.preferenceData]})
                                }
                            }}
                            >
                            <View style={styles.view4}>
                                <View style={styles.view5}>
                                    <View style={styles.view6}>
                                        <CheckBox 
                                        center
                                        checkedIcon='check-square-o'
                                        uncheckedIcon='square-o'
                                        checked={item.checked}
                                        checkedColor={COLORS.primary}
                                        /> 
                                        <Text style={styles.text5}>{item.name}</Text>
                                    </View>
                                    <Text style={styles.text6}>RM.{item.price.toFixed(2)}</Text>
            
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                            
                    )}
                </View>
            </View>
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
```

dummyData code

```
menu:[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "Chicken Fajita",
        photo: images.Chicken_Fajita,
        description: "Grilled Chicken Breast, Onion, Bell Pepper, Fajita Sauce",
        price: 20.00,
        rating:3,
        reviews:89,
        preferenceData: [

            [{name:"Garlic Sauce",price:8.91,checked:false,id:0},{name:"Cocktail Sauce",price:8.75,checked:false ,id:1},{name:'Chili Sauce',price:11.99 ,checked:false,id:2},
            {name:'ketchip Sauce',price:11.99 ,checked:false,id:3},
            ],
    
            [{name:"7up",price:8.90 ,checked:false,id:0 },{name:"Fanta Orange",price:8.90 ,checked:false,id:1},{name:'Sprite',price:11.90,checked:false ,id:2},
            {name:'Dew',price:3.95 ,checked:false,id:3},{name:'100Plus',price:3.95 ,checked:false,id:4},{name:'Apple Juice',price:10.95 ,checked:false,id:5},
            {name:'Strawberry Shake',price:16.95 ,checked:false,id:6},{name:'Chocolate Shake',price:16.95 ,checked:false,id:7},
            ],
    
            [{name:"ٌRice",price:5.90,checked:false ,id:0},{name:"Shawarma",price:8.90,checked:false ,id:1},{name:'Mini Hummus',price:11.90,checked:false ,id:2},
            {name:'Lamb Arays',price:13.95 ,checked:false,id:3},{name:'Fine Cheese Kunafa',price:15.95 ,checked:false,id:4},{name:'Almond Basbousa',price:10.95,checked:false ,id:5},
            {name:'Mix Baklava Nuts',price:16.95,checked:false ,id:6},{name:'Mini Muhallibyah',price:11.95 ,checked:false,id:7},{name:'Beef Tekkah',price:16.95 ,checked:false,id:8},
            ],
                
        ],
        minimum:[2,1,2,null,null],
        counter:[0,0,0,0,0],
        required: [true,true,true,false,false],  
    },
```

from the dummyData I can only able to add the main meal like Chicken Fajita and calculate its price but when I tick any appetizer like Garlic Sauce I can't add it to cart and also I can't calculate its price too. so please do help me out.